# Redirect full http-link to https-domain on another server

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I'm not sure if this even is possible to do, but I have two different domains on two different webservers. Both have a SSL-certificate. What I need is for all links on domain1 (both http and https) to be redirected to domain2 with https. Example:

http://domain1.com/customlink should be redirected to https://domain2.com/customlink

Also https://domain1.com/customlink should be redirected to the same as above.

Is this possible to achieve by having a .htaccess file with some rules on the webserver of domain1.com? It is important that whatever the user writes after domain1.com, also will be kept in the new redirected link.

Comment: This sounds like a relatively standard domain redirect? Is there a specific problem you are having?

Comment: It might seem so, my host told me that you cannot redirect "https://example.com/SOMETHING" and keep the part after slash onto the new domain, but I guess that was a lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this even is possible to do .... my host told me that you cannot redirect `https://example.com/SOMETHING` and keep the part after slash onto the new domain

I feel there must be something more to this question, as otherwise, this is just a standard domain redirect...

- two different domains on **two different webservers**
- Both have a SSL-certificate.
- Assuming there is only 1 domain (ie. `domain1.com`) hosted on the first server that you want to redirect.

Then, in your `.htaccess` file at `domain1.com`, use a mod_alias `Redirect`:

```
Redirect 302 / https://domain2.com/
```

You should remove all other directives in the `.htaccess` file at `domain1.com` in order to avoid potential conflicts (they aren't being used anyway, since you are redirecting everything).

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive is prefix-matching, and everything after the match is passed on to the target. eg. `/foo/bar/baz` is redirected to `https://domain2.com/foo/bar/baz`. *Everything* (HTTP and HTTPS) is redirected to `domain2.com` (HTTPS).

This is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended. This is to avoid any potential caching issues.

Comment: You are very right - this is nothing more than a normal redirect. I just got very confused from my host telling me it was not possible to redirect and keep the trailing part when you have SSL, for some reason. Thank you!